# Array_Search não funciona

Tags: php, array

Não localiza qual o número chave do Array. Código da página:

```
 $cnpj = "000000000000000";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/".$cnpj);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));
$texto = explode("<td>",$data);

$chave = array_search('Natureza Jurídica',$texto);

echo $chave;
print_r ($texto);
```

Código do Array:

```
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => CNPJ
    [2] => xxxxxxxxxxxx [ MATRIZ ]
    [3] => Nome da empresa
    [4] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [5] => Fantasia nome
    [6] => xxxxxxxxxxx
    [7] => Inicio atividade data
    [8] => xxxxx
    [9] => Natureza jurídica
    [10] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

Tentei fazer com Array_search para retornar o número do Array que esta o nome, mas não retorna. Tentei comando if e else mas também não retorna nada, como se a variável estivesse em branco.

Answer (score 2):

Se você está tentando pegar o índice do array, na posição da string "Natureza jurídica", observe que **array_search()** é *case-sensitive*. Vide [manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php):

> Se **needle** for uma string, a comparação é feita de uma maneira que diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas.

No array, o valor que deveria ser retornado é:

```
[9] => Natureza jurídica
```

Porém, aqui você está pesquisando com o "J" maiúsculo:

```
$chave = array_search('Natureza Jurídica',$texto);
```

O que faz com que **array_search()** retorne **false**.

Tente alterar a string de pesquisa, de forma que corresponda fielmente ao valor contido no array:

```
$chave = array_search('Natureza jurídica',$texto);
```

Comment: Arrumei a questão do maiúsculo e minúsculo e da mesma forma não deu certo.

Comment: +1. Corrigindo o Case,  o array_search funciona perfeitamente com o Array fornecido na pergunta: https://ideone.com/2rHzWY